# Cordova: dynamically loading a local image fails on Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova

In my Cordova app, I’m loading images dynamically from the local `/www/img` folder:

```
var imageURL = 'img/' + imageFilename;
element.css('background-image', "url('" + imageURL + "')");
```

It works fine in browser (`cordova run browser`), but fails for both Android and iOS (emulator + device).

What’s wrong?
What should local URLs for Cordova look like?

I’ve also tried with:

```
var imageURL = 'file:///img/' + imageFilename;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you ever get a solution to this? I am stuck with a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the common problem with file locations across mobile platforms.
 To navigate into app directory, you must use localizations from cordova file plugin.
 Like `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` which maps `/var/mobile/Applications/<UUID>/` on iOS and `file:///android_asset/` on Android.
Then you can easily create path to your resource like: `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "/yourDir/yourfile"`.
 For more information about cordova file paths, visit https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can use Cordova File without requesting write-file permissions?

Comment: Just tested it on Android. App is asking for permissions when you want to use some file manipulating function (like in camera plugin). If you want to use just variables that I mentioned it's ok to do it without permissions. I'm not sure about iOS.

Comment: Thanks for testing! With `run browser` I get a permission dialog just by adding the plugin (Chrome).